# Why can't I select my vertices on UV editor?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, vertices, uv-image-editor

https://gyazo.com/8d8423af9126666690069c96f1395e4c

Right now I'm up to the point where I need to apply textures to my creation. This problem I've run into involves me converting my bezier curves into mesh. Unfortunately, the mesh is not selectable on the uv editor, this hasn't been a problem with my sphere I have applied on the texture. Please help, I need to get this done.

Comment: try to press A to select all.

Comment: tried that, it does nothing that effects the uv editor

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: ??? @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Comment: Sounds like you're in pain or mask mode.

Comment: @Frederik Steinmetz  what mode do you switch it to and how?

Comment: Sorry, those modes are gone. Anyways, can you select anything pressing a? Does the problem persist with other objects? If you choose the box select tool at the very top of the UV editor three symbols appear. For "normal" selection make sure the leftmost is active.

Comment: @Frederik  ah! i got it working. i unchecked uv local view in the view section but thank you for the help!

Comment: glad to do it. Maybe you want to answer your own question, so others can spot it more easily?